# Jquery mobile click event binding twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two html pages one `index.html` and `groups.html` each page as **ul > li > a** list 
with different class names.

I have place the click events in a seperate js file as following :

```
// Index Page Onclick events

  $('body').on('click','.menuClass',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menuid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(menuid);        
  });

// click on groups html  >>  this page alert fires twice

$('body').on('click','.grpClass',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menuid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(menuid);

});
```

the script file is loaded in both the html files the second function for groups.html fires the click event twice.

Is there any way to avoid it or any better way to achieve the same?

Comment: have you tried to combine those 2 selectors into 1, since they essentially do the same at the moment? are you using AJAXed navigation or non-AJAXed one?

Comment: also, you might want to bind to vclick if you're using jQuery Mobile, since that is a standardized virtual event working cross-platform, while click might not work on some platforms

Comment: @ZathrusWriter : Thanks for `vlick` i understand that i can use selector but eventually there will be n pages so giving me n selectors .. looking for an elegant way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `stopImmediatePropagation()`, it will stop the event from bubbling through the DOM of your page:

```
// Index Page Onclick events

  $('body').on('click','.menuClass',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menuid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(menuid);        
  });

// click on groups html  >>  this page alert fires twice

$('body').on('click','.grpClass',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var menuid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(menuid);

});
```

Here is an example of how this works: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3yTQw/)**. If you click `test1`, the bubbling is prevented and only one alert is shown. If you click `test2`, the event is not stopped and you will get two alerts.

Comment: ha :) perfect I say :) ..Thank you!!1