# clearTimeout and clearInterval not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm having problems getting standard javascript timers to clear on mobile devices (Android and iOS, phone and tablet).
My page contains 2 buttons, a play/pause toggle and a stop button (both FontAwesome icons), the simple HTML for which is:

```
<span class="fa fa-pause control-button" id="pause-button"></span>
<span class="fa fa-stop control-button" id="stop-button"></span>
```

The interval is initiated with the following function:

```
var interval = function() {
    $('.control-button').fadeIn(300);
    //initiate the interval
    infiniteInterval = window.setInterval(Tiles.infiniteTick, speed); 
};
```

Where speed is defined in an earlier function (default is 300). infiniteTick is a very simple function which is working fine. I haven't explained it here as it would require an explanation of the whole program but I can provide code if required.

The play and pause toggles are as follows:

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '#pause-button', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-pause')) {
        window.clearInterval(infiniteInterval);
        $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
        $(this).addClass('fa-play');
    } else {
        infiniteInterval = window.setInterval(Tiles.infiniteTick, speed);
        $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
        $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
    }
});
```

Finally, the interval is terminated with this (some purely aesthetic extras removed for simplicity)

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '#stop-button', function() {
    window.clearInterval(infiniteInterval);
    $('.control-button').fadeOut(300);
});
```

I initially thought from researching this that it was due to click events not being properly registered, but as you can see I have added `touchstart` to all the click events and that has made no difference. It's working absolutely fine on all desktop browsers.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I'd be happy to answer any further questions.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I believe you have 2 handlers for same button. I'm not sure if it would work but if a class is the only way you want to decide, try` $(element).hasClass()`.

Comment: Thought it would be worth mentioning that on all devices, the other code in the functions does execute fine.

Comment: if you have access to a mac, you might try installing apple's developer tools, from there you can use the iPhone/iPad simulator in tandem with safari to debug javascript issues on mobile devices. try this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: Where in your code are you declaring `infiniteInterval`?

Comment: at the start of the module that these functions are contained in, `var infiniteInterval = null;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem, which it turns out was twofold.

Firstly, the click event was firing twice. This was fixed using this SO question: [jquery mobile click event fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660360/jquery-mobile-click-event-fires-twice)

Secondly, I wasn't properly clearing the intervals.

**Edited with @MjrKusanagi's comments**

A simple call to `clearInterval()` before every `setInterval()` call has fixed the problem, making sure that the interval was always reset before starting again.

**Original sketchy workaround:**

I've called

```
 infiniteInterval = null;
```

after every `clearInterval()` call, as well as wrapping the `setInterval()` calls with

```
if (infiniteInterval === null)
```

Thanks to everyone who commented and hopefully this will help someone sometime :)

Comment: Setting infiniteInterval to null should not clear the interval. In fact I'm fairly confident that this is not what fixed your problem. The variable infiniteInterval is just holding an integer number. Setting it to another value (like null) has nothing to do with actually clearing the interval.

Comment: That's what I thought yeah. It works though, if you know why I'd love to hear :)

Comment: Checking if its null just prevents you from accidentally changing the pointer before clearing the interval associated with it. I.think it would be a better design pattern to always clear the interval before setting it to another value.

Comment: If you want to test this to yourself: 1. Stop Checking if infiniteInterval is null. 2. Then before every instance of setInterval, add a call to clearInteral.

Comment: If you agree thats the correct solution, edit this answer and explain why, then accept your own answer. Ill upvote this too.

Comment: Done, thanks. Can't accept my answer for 2 days but will do.

Answer (score 1):

First, your click event is firing twice because of this sentence:

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '#pause-button', function() { ...
```

It listens to two events `click` and `touchstart`, thus it will be triggered twice, once on `click` event and once on `touchstart` event. This is also why your code works well on pc because there's no `touchstart` event in pc browsers.

So every time you touch that button, things happened like this:

- 1st event triggered

  - interval set, handle id is 1 (for example)
  - infiniteInterval = 1
- 2nd event triggered

  - another interval set, handle id is 2
  - infiniteInterval = 2

And now there's two timing cycles running instead of one, and you only have track of the second one. When you invoke `clearInterval`, only the `handle id = 2` interval is cleared, and `1` is still running.

So the solution is:

1. Fix the twice-triggered events problem, by only listen to `click`. (try `fastclick` or `zepto` or other lib to deal with the click latency on mobile devices)
2. As your own answer said, set `infiniteInterval` to `null`, and if it is not `null` do not ever start another interval. (I think it is more elegant than "always clear before setting" works, as `infiniteInterval` works as a flag of running interval)

Hope these could solve your problem.